# Can't move an iFrame down in a table HTML

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to move an iframe down in a table so it is inline with the image.

A screenshot http://prntscr.com/758oku

The code I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:67%" border="10">
<tr>
<td vertical-align: top style="vertical-align:top;" style="width: 70%" ><img src="https://example.com/example.jpg" alt="web-image" style="width:200px;height:200px">  </td>
<td vertical-align: center style="width: 25%">  <iframe src="http://example.com/tsstatustext.php" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center">
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to move the iframe (online) down so it is on the same line as the information

Comment: I can't see the screenshot so I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but looking at your code, my guess is you need to do one or both of the following: **a)** add `style="height: 200px;"` to your `<iframe>`, or **b)** add `vertical-align: bottom;` to the style attribute of the `<img>` and second `<td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your code, as it is now, should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:67%;" border="10">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;width: 70%;" ><img src="https://example.com/example.jpg" alt="web-image" style="width:200px;height:200px">  </td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;width: 25%">  <iframe src="http://example.com/tsstatustext.php" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center">
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

to add some white space above the image use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:67%;" border="10">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;width: 70%;" ><img src="https://example.com/example.jpg" alt="web-image" style="width:200px;height:200px">  </td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;width: 25%">  <iframe src="http://example.com/tsstatustext.php" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" style="padding:20px;">
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Just adjust the pixel amount of padding to achieve the desired result.